# Hi I want to know if the correct written characters for boketto (To daydream) is spelled ぼけっと or ボケっと

Tags: grammar, spelling

Hi I want to know if the correct written characters for boketto (To daydream) is spelled ぼけっと or ボケっと

Answer (score 1):

ボケっと seems to be used primarily for describing someone spacing out and being unproductive, as shown here in these example sentences.

https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/101580/boketto-boketto

> たまにまる一日**ぼけっと**していても別に悪い事じゃない。
>   It's no crime to just idle the whole day once in a while.
>
> **ボケッと**しないで、さっさとメモ書きなさいよっ。
>   Don't just stand there like a lump, start taking notes!

Answer (score 0):

I think both spellings are acceptable. You can google search them and see how many hits you get. I got the following:

> - ぼけっと
>     About 525,000,000 results (0.62 seconds)
> - ボケっと
>     About 584,000,000 results (0.67 seconds)

Comment: Those are results without quotation marks, right? Not that it really changes the reality of whether both are acceptable or not, but those results don't really have any meaning without quotations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for my ignorance.